# How to update Primefaces components present on child window?

Tags: ajax, jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

Here is my code:

```
<p:commandLink  actionListener="#{formBean.fillForm}" oncomplete="window.open('#{facesContext.externalContext.requestContextPath}/forms/BP008ACT0001_fv_1.xhtml?','_blank');" value="click" 
    <f:param name="stDocNo" value="#{row.get('msm006_msa001')}" />
    <f:param name="stTrxNo" value="#{row.get('msm006_msa002')}" />
</p:commandLink>
```

I am trying to pass 'stDocNo' and 'stTrxNo' parameters to properties of bean named formBean. These properties are then used by label components present on 'BP008ACT0001_fv_1.xhtml' that is being opened on click of p:commandLink. The issue that I am facing is that the labels present on child window do not show the param values that have been passed through `<p:commandLink>`.

can anybody tell me what I'm missing out here in my code?

Answer (score 0):

Can you debug your code in actionListner method formBean.fillForm() when button is clicked and see whether the prams are passing into backing beans or not. First your request goes to fillForm() method and then when its processing gets completed then onComplete() is called and new window will be open. Now you can also check at this point either your parameter is going properly or not.

Comment: Like you said I have tried debugging metod fillForm thats called on click of commandLink. parameters are passed properly to the bean but their value is not displayed on page that is being opened on complete event.

Comment: Are you using same form bean on BP008ACT0001_fv_1.xhtml page. Can you please post your code where you are getting the parameter from request object etc